# spring mvc transport json to object

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc

I am trying to post a json using ajax to my spring mvc controller I am using code like this in my js file:

```
$('#regist').click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'user/regist',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    type: 'post',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        var json = JSON.stringify(data);
                        alert(json);
                    },
                    fail: function (errMsg) {
                        alert(errMsg);
                    },
                    data: JSON.stringify({
                        'IDCard': '1234567890'
                    })
                })
            });
```

the signature of my controller function is like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/regist", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ResultJson regist(HttpSession session, @RequestBody RegistFormJson json)
```

the RegistFormJson goes like this:

```
public class RegistFormJson  {
    private String IDCard;

    public String getIDCard() {
        return IDCard;
    }

    public void setiDCard(String IDCard) {
        this.IDCard = IDCard;
    }
}
```

now when I send my request, and what I get from my controller using

```
logger.info(json.getIDCard);
```

is **null**.When I change my bean propertity to **idCard** and change my other code as well ,I can get the result successfully. Who can tell me why ? And If I want to use **IDCard** in my code, how can I get the result .Thanks

Comment: Have you tried adding it to a variable? var obj = { "IDCard":"1234567890"}; and sending that as the data? data: JSON.stringify(obj)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring comes with Jackson API which uses Standard Java Code Convention to map JSON properties to Java models.

Since `IDCard` is not in lower camel case, Jackson API is not able to map the JSON property.

To overcome this you need to specify a `@JsonProperty("IDCard")` annotation on a Java attribute in order to use `IDCard` for your JSON property.

Likewise, you can set the `PropertyNamingStrategy` on the `ObjectMapper` to overcome this issue.

Comment: I followed your suggess, and add `@JsonProperty` before `private String IDCard;` It works! thanks!!